# Creating a new project out of a branch

Tags: git

Some time ago we made a branch from our master branch in Git. Currently, this branch has diverged so much that it makes no sense merging it into the master and we consider creating a new project out of it.

Is there any Git functionality that would allow us creating a new independent project out of this branch, keeping all the history?

Comment: What did you try? Just create a new project, set the remote in your checkout to the new project and push ?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I was not clear enough. In plain words, what I need is that a branch A from a project B becomes itself a totally independent project C. I don't see how your suggestion is going to help me.

Comment: Yes, you can simply push only branch A to the remote of project C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
git clone --branch A --single-branch B C
```

[`--branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone--bltnamegt) tells Git to use branch `A` as the current branch in the new repo (instead of the `master` branch of the original repo).

[`--single-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---no-single-branch) tells it to copy into the clone only the commits that are reachable from the current branch (set here using `--branch`).

`B` is the original repository (a local directory or an URL), `C` is the local directory where to create the clone.

In the new repo, Git sets the original repo (`B`) as the `origin` remote. If you don't need this link you can remove it any time: just run `git remote remove origin` in the new repo.